# Firebase exception error for macOS app Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

When I try to run the simulator for my macOS app, which is using Firebase, it gives this error: "Thread 1: "The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the default Authinstance can be initialized. One way to ensure this is to call `FirebaseApp.configure()` in the App Delegate's `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` (or the `@main` struct's initializer in SwiftUI)." I notice this happened after I created an environment object.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseCore


@main
struct testagainApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            let viewModel = AppViewModel()
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
             
              
        }
        .windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
}
```

If I get rid of let viewModel = AppViewModel() and .environmentObject(viewModel), the simulator runs just fine. If I put the app delegate first, the simulator runs but nothing appears. I am new to Swift and am unsure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
I faced same issue a while ago, then noticed that I have not linked the

`GoogleService-Info.plist` file to the project, if you see its already added then better remove and add it to the project via Xcode again.

Hope that solves your issue.

**Option 2:**
Make sure you don't have more two copies of Firebase linked into your app. If so you can remove one. See this doc on [the Firebase iOS SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/docs/firebase_in_libraries.md) for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not yet found the solution. I have the plist file. I downloaded Firebase using Swift Packet Manager, which I believe is automatically a static framework. I did not make any changes when adding Firebase, so I am still unsure as to why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Instead of using the `AppDelegate` I used the App's initializer:

```swift
struct testagainApp: App {
  init() {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
  }
  // ...
}
```